# As a user, can I request that a question I asked in SE philosophy before to be moved to SE physics?

Tags: support, migration

In the help section it says that the site moderators have the option to migrate a post to any site. As a user, can I request that a question I asked before to be moved to a new SE site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could flag to request such a move *but* for a migration to go through, generally the question would have to be good or great *and* be on topic on the target site. The best reason is "in need of moderator intervention" then fill in the details of where and *why* you want the post moved.

I'd wonder though how a question would be on topic on philosophy and physics.

So you *could* but whether it goes through is entirely on the merits of the migration.